# XSS strip tag bypass

Tags: xss

I'm studying and I really need some help, I've this code:

`$param1 = strip_tags($_GET['var2'], '<>');`

I'm trying all kinds of things, like:

```
$_GET['var2'] = "Hello <img src=x onerror=confirm(1)"+"\xA9";
OR    
$_GET['var2'] =   '\074script\076\141\154\145\162\164\050\061\051\074/script\076';
OR
$_GET['var2'] = "\074\163\143\162\151\160\164\076\141\154\145\162\164\050\061\051\074\057\163\143\162\151\160\164\076";
```

Plus many other possibilities.

I want to see the alert popup, be able to run an XSS attack.
The thing is, none of that works. Could someone point me in a direction? Or is it just impossible to bypass that?

Comment: "None of that works" - what is it you're considering to mean, "working?"

Comment: Work means to show the alert(1), xss experts will understand. Thankyou